# How to mark required field in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, xval

I'm using jQuery Validate and xVal to validate in input forms. This works great.
However, I do want to mark my required fields with an asterix (*) or something like that to show which field is actually required.

I could do this by hand, but since I already generate my validation rules with xVal I thought I could mark the required fields automatically based on the provided rules.

Is there a way to hook into either xVal or jQuery Validate to retrieve the rules, or somehow make them mark my required fields?

I'm using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery Validate.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Give the class `required` to the form elements, and use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('<span style="color:red;">*</span>').insertAfter('.required');
});
```

This will attach "*" to every elements with `required` class

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, that would probably work if they had the required class, but as far as I know, xVal does not set the classes, but rather provide the rules directly to jQuery Validate.

I guess the rules live in memory or something.

Comment: Would you upload some code then? I would like to see how the validation function is attached to the element.

Comment: This is the jQuery Validation code that is generated, http://gist.github.com/482877. As for xVal, you can get the code here, http://xval.codeplex.com/. I can provide a gist for that as well if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible

1. Get all the inputs in form
2. Iterate and find if the input has rule *required*
3. If Yes, find the label of that input
4. Append * at the end of the label text

Your code will look something like this

```
    $.each($("#you-form input"), function( index, element ) {
      var rule =  $(element).rules() ; // this will get the rules for each input
      if(rule && rule.required) {
        //find label and append red *
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easiest to make a separate "rules" variable which you pass to both jQuery and some other function. This other function would loop through it and mark all required fields as such.

Comment: That could work, but I don't want to modify xVal to accomplish this.
To generate my validation rules from my edit model, I use this line of code: 

Html.ClientSideValidation<NewCompanyInput>()